# "Refactor code so that stream pipeline is used" when assigning stream to a variable before passing to method

Tags: java, intellij-idea, java-stream

I have the following method:

```java
public int parseIntStream(Stream<Integer> stream) {
    return stream.reduce(0, Integer::sum);
}
```

When I try to pass a stream like so, IntelliJ gives me the warning `Refactor code so that stream pipeline is used`:

```java
Stream<int> intStream = Stream.of("a","b","c").map(letter -> letter.equals("a") ? 1 : (letter.equals("b") ? 2 : (letter.equals("c") ? 3 : 0)));
int x = parseIntStream(intStream);
```

However, if I don't assign the first stream to a variable, the warning goes away:

```java
int x = parseIntStream(Stream.of("a","b","c").map(letter -> letter.equals("a") ? 1 : (letter.equals("b") ? 2 : (letter.equals("c") ? 3 : 0))));
```

I know `map` is an intermediate operation, but I'm not trying to terminate the stream until I pass it to the method. I'm not even using the stream until then. I am only assigning it at the beginning for the sake of readability.

Comment: If this is your code, you have a couple compiler errors to fix first.  You can't have a primitive type as a type argument, so `Stream<int>` doesn't compile.  In addition, `Integer::sum` doesn't match the `Stream<String>` parameter of `parseIntStream`, which causes an error in calling that method also.

Comment: Let me fix it. It's just placeholder code I wrote to simulate my use case.

Comment: You can always disable that annoying warning. Code readability is more important than making Intellij happy.

Comment: Of course I don't mind disabling that warning, but I couldn't Google whether or not what I was doing was correct and the warning is unnecessary. Also, the fact that it disappears when I remove the assignment confused me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some type mismatches which javac and the IDE are trying to accommodate.  Use `mapToInt` rather than `map` to produce an `IntStream`.  The `IntStream` has its own `sum` method so you don't have to write one.

```
int sum = Stream.of("a","b","c").mapToInt( <your-map-function> ).sum();
```